# Fancyhdr: Display current Subsection OR Section, depending on what is current in Header line

Tags: fancyhdr

How can I tell LateX and Fancyhdr to display the section or subsection in the header?
I can figure out (from e.g. here: [Header with section name](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244128/header-with-section-name)) how to tell it to display the Section, with `\leftmark`, but then it displays the super-ordinate chapter title even if there's a subsection on the page. Or I can use `\rightmark`but then it only displays subsection titles, and if the current chapter is a super-ordinate section the header is blank.

How can I do both, so if it's a section it shows that, and if it's a subsection that's current, it shows that?

These should NOT alternate, so each page header should show the same (so not odd pages do one thing, even another)

MWE:

```
% Options for packages loaded elsewhere
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
%
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%%\usepackage[]{nohyperref}%%


%% HEADINGS
\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pt}{5.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}
{0pt}{5.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{0.3ex plus .2ex}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\singlespacing}

% HEADINGS & SECTIONS%
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{color}
%\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}


\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
    \markboth{\thesection\quad #1}{}}
%% FANCY HEADER %%
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf[]{}
\fancyhead[R]{Author \thepage}
%\fancyhead[C]{}

\fancyhead[L]{\rightmark}         %<----------------- or \leftmark%

\newlength\FHoffset
\setlength\FHoffset{1cm}
\fancyheadoffset{\FHoffset}


% START DOCUMENT %


\begin{document}


% START BODY %



\section{Chapter One: Lorem}
abc
\clearpage


\subsection{Subchapter 1.1: Ipsum}

def
\clearpage

\section{Chapter Two: Doloret}
ghi 
\clearpage
\subsection{Subchapter 2.1: Whatever}






\end{document}
```

Comment: `\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\thesubsection\quad #1}{}}`? Then subsection will update the left mark too. Or `\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
    \markboth{\thesection\quad #1}{\thesection\quad #1}}`  so that section updates also the right mark.

Comment: The first one did it, perfect, thanks! Would it be a lot more difficult to limit the sub/section header to whatever comes before a colon? That would just make the header shorter. Thanks :)

Comment: The thing that ended up working was `\sectionmark{}`. This can be a shorter version of the sectionheads that then show up in the header.